# Issues with multibranch pipeline job DSL

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-groovy

I am having issues with multibranch pipeline for job DSL plugin to automate the creation of multibranch pipeline job.

The piece am having issues with is how to let set the path to the Jenkinsfile on the repo. I have looked online for documentation but found nothing to help. I have even tried to get example scripts but multibranch job DSL scripts are rare on the internet. Matter of fact could not find any that has Jenkinsfile set in it

**jobs.groovy**

```
folderName = "${JENKINS_PATH}"

folder(folderName)


multibranchPipelineJob("${folderName}/jenkins_multibranch_devops") {
    branchSources {
        git {
            remote("https://gitlab.com/${REPO_PATH}")
            credentialsId('gitlab_credentials')
            includes('*')
        }
    }
    configure { project ->
        project / factory {
            scriptPath('jenkins/Jenkinsfile')
        }
    }
    orphanedItemStrategy {
        discardOldItems {
            numToKeep(14)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what i have and its failing because i am obviously missing some stuffs which is why am looking for help

What am i missing and where can i get documentation if i plan  on adding more and more to this jobs.groovy file and want to know how to know what stuffs to add because current doc page doesn't help at all

Comment: seems this will never get an answer..i mean multibranch pipeline for jenkins? many thousands of people use jenkins and certainly use multibranch pipelines..oh well

Answer (score 1):

You can set it using this:

```
multibranchPipelineJob("${folderName}/jenkins_multibranch_devops") {
  branchSources {
    git {
      remote("https://gitlab.com/${REPO_PATH}")
      credentialsId('gitlab_credentials')
      includes('*')
    }
  }
  factory {
    workflowBranchProjectFactory {
      scriptPath('jenkins/Jenkinsfile')
    }
  }
  orphanedItemStrategy {
    discardOldItems {
      numToKeep(14)
    }
  }
}
```

Documentation is available through the Job DSL API viewer in your jenkins installation: https://{your-jenkins}/plugin/job-dsl/api-viewer/index.html

Comment: where does this code snippet belong? can you post full code to know where this section will be placed? thanks

Comment: also can you point me to the place in documentation where it gives how to write groovy file for multibranch pipeline??? i obviously know that url already but did not find anything helpful regarding "multibranch pipelines"

Comment: I updated the code snippet based on your code. Hope that helps!

Comment: Here is a good place to start for multibranch pipeline https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/

Comment: still could not find the jenkinsfile..so the scriptpath is not working...the jenkinsfile is under `jenkins/Jenkinsfile` so not sure why its not seeing it...i even put the Jenkinsfile in defualt root directory location and still cant find the Jenkinsfile

Comment: weird..just re-scanned it after running the seed job and finally found the Jenkinsfile...pretty weird there..anyways will try this back and forth and then see if this solves my issues..thanks alot for the answer

Comment: You can run branch indexing automatically by doing `queue("${folderName}/jenkins_multibranch_devops")`

Comment: the url you gave me has NOTING about `multibranch pipelines` it only has stuffs about regular pipelines...one last help from you since no documentation on these things...how do i add configure block to your above snippet..lets say you want to add a configure block with some stuffs..how will that look like?

Comment: for example lets say i want to add configure block to only discovery branches that starts with `v*` e.g `v2.0` ...how will that look like?

Comment: Use the `includes()` that you already have, just change the pattern. Something like `includes('v*')`

Comment: There is a lot of documentation around Job DSL on the wiki: https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki
Also the API viewer: https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/
Regarding multibranch pipeline there is a lot of information in the sub pages to that link I posted. Is there some specific thing about multibranch pipeline that you have questions about?

Comment: well i thought that needed a configure block..well how will aconfigure block look like then? lets say i want to run some shell commands under configure block..how will that look like?....you keep saying there are documentation but none of the links you sent have anything for multibranch pipeline..if you notice i only ask about multibranch pipeline because i am ok with regular pipeline job DSL...only issue is the multibranch pipeline one as there is limited documentation

Comment: You don't need a configure block. Things like shell commands are done in the Jenkinsfile when using multibranch pipeline. You can read about it in the links posted above.

Comment: configure is also present in job dsl script https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/The-Configure-Block