# Parametrize withCredentials block in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to parameterize the credentials block in my Jenkinsfile and not able to do so.

Here is what i currently have

```
stage("Deploy") {

  if ("${ENVIRONMENT}"=='dev') {
      wrap([$class: 'VaultBuildWrapper', configuration: configuration, vaultSecrets: secrets]) {
        withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'secret1_dev', variable: 'SECRET1'), string(credentialsId: 'secret2_dev', variable: 'SECRET2'),string(credentialsId: 'secret3_dev', variable: 'SECRET3'), string(credentialsId: 'secret4_dev', variable: 'SECRET4'),string(credentialsId: 'secret5_dev', variable: 'SECRET5'), string(credentialsId: 'secret6_dev', variable: 'SECRET6')]){
  } else {
      wrap([$class: 'VaultBuildWrapper', configuration: configuration, vaultSecrets: secrets]) {
        withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'secret1_qa', variable: 'SECRET1'), string(credentialsId: 'secret2_qa', variable: 'SECRET2'),string(credentialsId: 'secret3_qa', variable: 'SECRET3'), string(credentialsId: 'secret4_qa', variable: 'SECRET4'),string(credentialsId: 'secret5_qa', variable: 'SECRET5'), string(credentialsId: 'secret6_qa', variable: 'SECRET6')]){
  }
        sh """
        export DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT=${ENVIRONMENT}
        source ~/.bashrc
        echo 'parametrized credentials!'
        """
        }
      }
}
```

I am getting below error

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 58: expecting '}', found 'else' @ line 58, column 17.
                 } else {
                   ^
```

What i want to do is depending on what `ENVIRONMENT` is given to the job via parameter, it selects what `credentialsId` to pick for the secret variable am passing to the job.

Anyone know how to properly do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is simply down to your block nesting being incorrect. in programming languages like Groovy (in this case) that use curly braces to denote blocks, you open the blocks from the outermost to the innermost, then you close from innermost to outermost. E.g.

```
while(outer) {
    if (inner1) {
        echo "inner1"
    } else {
        echo "inner2"
    }
}
```

So for your case, it would look something like this (long lines wrapped for readability):

```
stage("Deploy") {
    if ("${ENVIRONMENT}"=='dev') {
        wrap(
            [
                $class: 'VaultBuildWrapper',
                configuration: configuration,
                vaultSecrets: secrets
            ]
        ) {
            withCredentials(
                [
                    string(credentialsId: 'secret1_dev', variable: 'SECRET1'),
                    string(credentialsId: 'secret2_dev', variable: 'SECRET2'),
                    string(credentialsId: 'secret3_dev', variable: 'SECRET3'),
                    string(credentialsId: 'secret4_dev', variable: 'SECRET4'),
                    string(credentialsId: 'secret5_dev', variable: 'SECRET5'),
                    string(credentialsId: 'secret6_dev', variable: 'SECRET6')
                ]
            ) {
                sh """
                    export DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT=${ENVIRONMENT}
                    source ~/.bashrc
                    echo 'parametrized credentials!'
                """
            }
        }
    } else {
        wrap(
            [
                $class: 'VaultBuildWrapper',
                configuration: configuration,
                vaultSecrets: secrets
            ]
        ) {
            withCredentials(
                [
                    string(credentialsId: 'secret1_qa', variable: 'SECRET1'),
                    string(credentialsId: 'secret2_qa', variable: 'SECRET2'),
                    string(credentialsId: 'secret3_qa', variable: 'SECRET3'),
                    string(credentialsId: 'secret4_qa', variable: 'SECRET4'),
                    string(credentialsId: 'secret5_qa', variable: 'SECRET5'),
                    string(credentialsId: 'secret6_qa', variable: 'SECRET6')
                ]
            ) {
                sh """
                    export DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT=${ENVIRONMENT}
                    source ~/.bashrc
                    echo 'parametrized credentials!'
                """
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, that seems unnecessarily duplicated, right? You want to only have one copy of your `sh` step, and for the correct credentials to be available within it, depending on the `${ENVIRONMENT}` variable. You could try storing the suffix for the credentials in a variable, and then using a GString for the name in each case. Something like this should do the trick (note: I haven't tried this out but I'm relatively confident that it should work):

```
stage("Deploy") {
    final String credentialSuffix = ENVIRONMENT == 'dev' ? 'dev' : 'qa'
    wrap(
        [
            $class: 'VaultBuildWrapper',
            configuration: configuration,
            vaultSecrets: secrets
        ]
    ) {
        withCredentials(
            [
                string(credentialsId: "secret1_${credentialSuffix}", variable: 'SECRET1'),
                string(credentialsId: "secret2_${credentialSuffix}", variable: 'SECRET2'),
                string(credentialsId: "secret3_${credentialSuffix}", variable: 'SECRET3'),
                string(credentialsId: "secret4_${credentialSuffix}", variable: 'SECRET4'),
                string(credentialsId: "secret5_${credentialSuffix}", variable: 'SECRET5'),
                string(credentialsId: "secret6_${credentialSuffix}", variable: 'SECRET6')
            ]
        ) {
            sh """
                export DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT=${ENVIRONMENT}
                source ~/.bashrc
                echo 'parametrized credentials!'
            """
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i had actually done the first option and was working while i wait for an answer on there since know it is DRY guilty..the second option is exactly what i was looking for. Just tried it and it worked!..now lets say i have a third of more option like `prod`..so dev, qa, prod and so on..how do i have this line ?

`final String credentialSuffix = ENVIRONMENT == 'dev' ? 'dev' : 'qa' : 'prod'`???

because when i tried that i got error because of the last `prod` section

Comment: That didn't look like what you were attempting to achieve based on your question: your code said "if environment is dev, then use credentials with dev suffix; but in all other cases use the ones with the qa suffix. :) Your self-answer derived from this is the way to make it dynamic like you want. Would you like to mark this as the accepted answer, or would you like me to update it with your further step also first?

Comment: well i have to simplify questions on here..so i had the simplified version so i can post on here..i mean my code is ofcourse bigger than this and i have to leave things out..so yeah follow up questions came up to solve another issue BUT ended up i could just pass the parameters like that without needing elvis operator

Comment: maybe you can help with this question as well as no one will help.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52142190/issues-with-multibranch-pipeline-job-dsl

Answer (score 1):

i will accept @gerard-ryan answer but this is simplify what i needed
derived from his answer

```
stage("Deploy") {
    wrap(
        [
            $class: 'VaultBuildWrapper',
            configuration: configuration,
            vaultSecrets: secrets
        ]
    ) {
        withCredentials(
            [
                string(credentialsId: "secret1_${ENVIRONMENT}", variable: 'SECRET1'),
                string(credentialsId: "secret2_${ENVIRONMENT}", variable: 'SECRET2'),
                string(credentialsId: "secret3_${ENVIRONMENT}", variable: 'SECRET3'),
                string(credentialsId: "secret4_${ENVIRONMENT}", variable: 'SECRET4'),
                string(credentialsId: "secret5_${ENVIRONMENT}", variable: 'SECRET5'),
                string(credentialsId: "secret6_${ENVIRONMENT}", variable: 'SECRET6')
            ]
        ) {
            sh """
                export DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT=${ENVIRONMENT}
                source ~/.bashrc
                echo 'parametrized credentials!'
            """
        }
    }
}
```

I did not the final string section as i already have the `ENVIRONMENT` parameterized